# Is there a way to update a column A from a table T1 using column B from table T2 based in a group of conditions in R?

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I'm trying to create a code in R similar to the following:

```
UPDATE Table_1 A SET Column_1= 
(SELECT Column_2 FROM Tabla_2 WHERE
Column_3=A.Column_3 AND
Column_4=A.Column_4
HAVING INDEX=MIN(INDEX));
```

For example, having these data frames:

```
Table_1 <-data.frame(
  Column_1=c(1,1,1,1),
  Column_3=c("1","2","3","1"),
  Column_4=c("A","B","C","A")
)


Table_2<-data.frame(
  Column_2 =c(2,3,4,5),
  Column_3=c("1","2","3","4"),
  Column_4=c("A","B","C","D")
)
```

I want to update Table 1 to end up looking like:

```
Table_1 <-data.frame(
  Column_1=c(2,3,4,2),
  Column_3=c("1","2","3","1"),
  Column_4=c("A","B","C","A")
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can do a join and assign (`:=`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Table_1)[Table_2, Column_1 := Column_2, on = .(Column_4)]
Table_1
#   Column_1 Column_3 Column_4
#1:        2        1        A
#2:        3        2        B
#3:        4        3        C
#4:        2        1        A
```

Comment: I just add a reproducible example